# How can I prove that the following series does not converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How can I prove that the following series does not converge uniformly for $|y|<1$? could anyone give me a hint please?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{2n-1},$$

Comment: @Nosrati I was writing the exact same answer when I read your comment.

Comment: Don't feel sorry. I had forgotten I had already answered the (almost) exact question.

Comment: But is not the series in the link different from what the OP asked about .... because the y she mentioned is independent on n while the y in the link dependent on n @Julián Aguirre

Comment: It is almost the same. One has $z^n$, the other $y^n$. One $n$ in the denominator, the other $2n-1$. The same method applies.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre " the y she mentioned is independent on n while the y in the link dependent on n"